# What's the difference between BSTR and _bstr_t?

Tags: c++, com, smart-pointers

Can anyone explain the difference between the types mentioned above and some sample usage to clearly explain the difference between the two?

Any help would be highly appreciated!
Note: this question is a spin-off from [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/324168/msxml2ixmldomdocument2ptr-getxml-messing-up-my-string)

Answer (score 29, accepted):

`BSTR` is the string data type used with COM.

`_bstr_t` is a wrapper class that works like a smart pointer, so it will free the allocated memory when the variable is destroyed or goes out of scope.
`_bstr_t` also has reference counting, which increases every time you pass the `_bstr_t` variable by value (avoiding unnecessary copy) and decrement when it is no longer used. Whenever all references are destroyed, the allocated memory for the string is freed.

An alternative to `BSTR` is the `CComBSTR`. It also manages the memory for the `BSTR`, but has no reference counting.

Answer (score 15):

**BSTR** is a raw pointer, while **`_bstr_t`** is a class encapsulating that pointer.

It's the same difference as **char*** vs. **std::string**.

Answer (score 11):

_bstr_t wraps the BSTR type. So, when you instantiate a _bstr_t, you are also creating BSTR. _bstr_t simply wraps everything up for you and acts sort of like a "smart ptr" to the BSTR.

BSTR

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms221069.aspx

SysAllocString()

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms891285.aspx

_bstr_t

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zthfhkd6.aspx